Hyphenation issue in multilingual dokument: CZECH and SANSKIRT
In following MNWE example, the hyphenation in Czech text is missing.
MNWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a6paper}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{sanskrit-devanagari}
% \babelfont{rm}{TeX Gyre Termes}   % <- not necessary use. 
\babelfont[sanskrit-devanagari]{rm}{Shobhika}

\begin{document}
  Ve třetí části velkého indického eposu Mahábhárata se mocný duch Jakša ptá nejstaršího a
  nejmoudřejšího Pánduovce \foreignlanguage{sanskrit-devanagari}{पाण्‍डव} o němž pojednává
  staroindický epos \emph{Mahábhárata}. Judhišthiry, jaké je největší ze všech mysterií.

  Šiva (Devanágarí: \foreignlanguage{sanskrit-devanagari}{शिव})

  Zdá se vám to podivné? Je to jako sledovat Slunce při úchvatném západu, kdy pomalu mizí za
  vzdálenými mraky. Avšak vy si náhle uvědomíte, že se nehýbe Slunce, ale že jev je způsoben
  otáčením zeměkoule. Ve své mysli spatříte celou naši planetu - včetně vás samotných - jak se otáčí
  na opačnou stranu směrem od Slunce. V tom okamžiku pohlédnete na svět

\end{document}

As you can see in figure below, when macro \foreignlanguage (right picture) is used, the hyphenation is lost. How solve. Is there any solution with fontspec and babel. I can't use polyglossia because it leads into another sort of issues with biblatex combination.
I am using lualatex and my Miktex distribution is up to date.

LogFile:
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.1 (MiKTeX 24.4) (format=lualatex 2024.9.9)  9 SEP 2024 21:44
 restricted system commands enabled.
**grain0089_c.tex
(./grain0089_c.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-08-16>
Lua module: luaotfload 2024-02-14 3.28 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/lu
atex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2023-12-28.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luaotfload/font
loader-2023-12-28.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.134
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/lu
atex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'. (C:/Users/HP/AppData/Lo
cal/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

(.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

(.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)

(.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.
sty
Package: scrlfile-hook 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)


(.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty
Package: scrlogo 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (logo)
))) (.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
Applying: [2021/05/01] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line 252.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line
 368.
))
(.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip49
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box52
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
...

(.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize12pt.cl
o
File: scrsize12pt.clo 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt
)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/MiKT
eX/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
(.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package: typearea 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip50
\ta@div=\count192
\ta@hblk=\skip51
\ta@vblk=\skip52
\ta@temp=\skip53
\footheight=\skip54
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 12
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 448.13095pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 27.31467pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = -22.47766pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 635.5pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -41.72441pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 18.125pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 21.75pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 12.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 50.75pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 14.5pt
(typearea)              on input line 1799.
)
\c@part=\count193
\c@chapter=\count194
\c@section=\count195
\c@subsection=\count196
\c@subsubsection=\count197
\c@paragraph=\count198
\c@subparagraph=\count199
\scr@dte@chapter@maxnumwidth=\skip55
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\chapter on input line 5990.
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip56
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\section on input line 6001.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\section on input line 6001.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip57
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=true'
(scrbook)           for `\part on input line 6010.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip58
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsection on input line 6020.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsection on input line 6020.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip59
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsubsection on input line 6030.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsubsection on input line 6030.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip60
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\paragraph on input line 6041.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\paragraph on input line 6041.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip61
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subparagraph on input line 6051.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subparagraph on input line 6051.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip62
\belowcaptionskip=\skip63
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box53
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 7242.
\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip64
\c@figure=\count266
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 7259.
\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip65
\c@table=\count267
Class scrbook Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 7430.
\bibindent=\dimen140
) (.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(...MiKTeX/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(.../MiKTeX/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count268
\Gm@cntv=\count269
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count270
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen141
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen142
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen143
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen144
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen145
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen146
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen147
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen148
\Gm@dimlist=\toks18

(.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.cfg))
(.../MiKTeX/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2024/08/29 v24.9 The Babel package

(.../MiKTeX/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def
\bbl@readstream=\read2
\l@afrikaans=\language2
Package babel Info: Non-standard hyphenation setup on input line 117.
\l@ancientgreek=\language3
\l@armenian=\language4
\l@assamese=\language5
\l@basque=\language6
\l@belarusian=\language7
\l@bengali=\language8
\l@bokmal=\language9
\l@bulgarian=\language10
\l@catalan=\language11
\l@churchslavonic=\language12
\l@classiclatin=\language13
\l@coptic=\language14
\l@croatian=\language15
\l@czech=\language16
\l@danish=\language17
\l@dutch=\language18
\l@esperanto=\language19
\l@estonian=\language20
\l@ethiopic=\language21
\l@finnish=\language22
\l@french=\language23
\l@friulan=\language24
\l@galician=\language25
\l@georgian=\language26
\l@german=\language27
\l@greek=\language28
\l@gujarati=\language29
\l@hindi=\language30
\l@hungarian=\language31
\l@icelandic=\language32
\l@indonesian=\language33
\l@interlingua=\language34
\l@irish=\language35
\l@italian=\language36
\l@kannada=\language37
\l@kurmanji=\language38
\l@latin=\language39
\l@latvian=\language40
\l@lithuanian=\language41
\l@liturgicallatin=\language42
\l@macedonian=\language43
\l@malayalam=\language44
\l@marathi=\language45
\l@mongolian=\language46
\l@mongolianlmc=\language47
\l@monogreek=\language48
\l@ngerman=\language49
\l@nynorsk=\language50
\l@occitan=\language51
\l@oriya=\language52
\l@pali=\language53
\l@panjabi=\language54
\l@piedmontese=\language55
\l@polish=\language56
\l@portuguese=\language57
\l@romanian=\language58
\l@romansh=\language59
\l@russian=\language60
\l@sanskrit=\language61
\l@serbian=\language62
\l@serbianc=\language63
\l@slovak=\language64
\l@slovenian=\language65
\l@spanish=\language66
\l@swedish=\language67
\l@swissgerman=\language68
\l@tamil=\language69
\l@telugu=\language70
\l@thai=\language71
\l@turkish=\language72
\l@turkmen=\language73
\l@ukenglish=\language74
\l@ukrainian=\language75
\l@uppersorbian=\language76
\l@usenglishmax=\language77
\l@welsh=\language78
\babelcatcodetablenum=\catcodetable14
\bbl@pattcodes=\catcodetable15
)
\babel@savecnt=\count271
\U@D=\dimen149
\l@unhyphenated=\language79

(.../MiKTeX/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def
\bbl@attr@locale=\attribute4
)
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/arabi/bblopts.cfg
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
)
(.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/babel-czech/czech.ldf
Language: czech 2008/07/06 v3.1a Czech support from the babel system
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 172.
\cs@wordlen=\count272
Package babel Info: Making - an active character on input line 226.

(.../MiKTeX/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadh
yph-cs.tex UTF-8 Czech hyphenation patterns
(.../MiKTeX/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/h
yph-cs.tex))))
(.../MiKTeX/tex/generic/babel/locale/cs/babel-cz
ech.tex
Package babel Info: Importing font and identification data for czech
(babel)             from babel-cs.ini. Reported on input line 11.
)
(.../MiKTeX/tex/generic/babel/locale/sa/babel-sa
nskrit-devanagari.tex)
Package babel Info: Importing data for sanskrit-devanagari
(babel)             from babel-sa-Deva.ini. Reported on input line 7.
Package babel Info: Hyphen rules for 'sanskrit-devanagari' set to \l@sanskrit
(babel)             (\language61). Reported on input line 7.

(.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.s
ty (.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2024-08-16 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex
.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2024-05-08 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count273
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box54
))
Package: xparse 2024-08-16 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: fontspec 2024/05/11 v2.9e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2024/05/11 2.9e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
(.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.s
ty
Package: fontspec-luatex 2024/05/11 v2.9e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
eX
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count274
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count275
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count276
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count277
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count278
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count279
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count280
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count281
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count282
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count283
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count284
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen150
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen151
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen152
 (.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
(.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(./grain0089_c.aux

Package babel Info: The following font families will use the default
(babel)             settings for all or some languages:
(babel)             * \rmfamily = lmr
(babel)               [lmroman12-regular]:+tlig;
(babel)             * \sffamily = lmss
(babel)               [lmsans12-regular]:+tlig;
(babel)             * \ttfamily = lmtt
(babel)               [lmmono12-regular]:
(babel)             There is nothing intrinsically wrong with it, but
(babel)             'babel' will no set Script and Language, which could
(babel)             be relevant in some languages. If your document uses
(babel)             these families, consider redefining them with \babelfont.
(babel)             Reported on input line 4.

)
\openout1 = grain0089_c.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 1
1.
 (.../MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: luatex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: luatex
* paper: a6paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: twoside 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(35.85083pt, 209.12683pt, 53.77628pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(50.5326pt, 294.76926pt, 75.79893pt)
* \paperwidth=298.75394pt
* \paperheight=421.10078pt
* \textwidth=209.12683pt
* \textheight=294.76926pt
* \oddsidemargin=-36.41916pt
* \evensidemargin=-18.49371pt
* \topmargin=-61.6124pt
* \headheight=18.125pt
* \headsep=21.75pt
* \topskip=12.0pt
* \footskip=50.75pt
* \marginparwidth=74.68849pt
* \marginparsep=12.8401pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.8pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)


Package fontspec Info: 
(fontspec)             Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmr/m/it on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/lmr/b/it on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 11.
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache loaded from C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/l
uatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc.
luaotfload | aux : font no 20 (nil) defines no feature for script dev2 with lang
uage san

Package fontspec Info: 
(fontspec)             Language 'Sanskrit' not explicitly supported within
(fontspec)             font 'Shobhika' with script 'Devanagari'. Check the
(fontspec)             typeset output, and if it is okay then ignore this
(fontspec)             warning. Otherwise a different font should be chosen.

luaotfload | aux : font no 20 (nil) defines no feature for script dev2 with lang
uage san

Package fontspec Info: 
(fontspec)             Could not resolve font "Shobhika/BI" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: 
(fontspec)             Could not resolve font "Shobhika/I" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).

luaotfload | aux : font no 23 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script dev2
 with language san
luaotfload | aux : font no 23 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script latn
 with language san
luaotfload | aux : font no 23 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script dflt
 with language san
luaotfload | aux : font no 23 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script dev2
 with language dflt
luaotfload | aux : font no 23 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script latn
 with language dflt
luaotfload | aux : font no 23 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script dflt
 with language dflt
luaotfload | aux : font no 24 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script dev2
 with language san
luaotfload | aux : font no 24 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script latn
 with language san
luaotfload | aux : font no 24 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script dflt
 with language san
luaotfload | aux : font no 24 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script dev2
 with language dflt
luaotfload | aux : font no 24 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script latn
 with language dflt
luaotfload | aux : font no 24 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script dflt
 with language dflt

Package fontspec Info: 
(fontspec)             Font family 'Shobhika(0)' created for font 'Shobhika'
(fontspec)             with options
(fontspec)             [Ligatures=TeX,Script=Devanagari,Language=Sanskrit,RawFe
ature={family=rm}].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:Shobhika:mode=node;script=dev2;language=SAN;+tl
ig;family=rm;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:Shobhika/B:mode=node;script=dev2;language=SAN;+
tlig;family=rm;"


(.../MiKTeX/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadh
yph-sa.tex UTF-8 Sanskrit hyphenation patterns
(.../MiKTeX/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/h
yph-sa.tex))
Overfull \hbox (9.84525pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--15
\TU/Shobhika(0)/m/n/12 पाण् डव \TU/lmr/m/n/12 o němž po-jed-náv
á sta-ro-in-dický epos
 []


Overfull \hbox (6.07324pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 18--22
\TU/lmr/m/n/12 vy si ná-hle uvě-do-míte, že se ne-hýbe Slunce,
 []


Overfull \hbox (7.0893pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 18--22
\TU/lmr/m/n/12 otáčí na opač-nou stranu smě-rem od Slunce.
 []



[1

{C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
(./grain0089_c.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-08-16>
 ***********


 *File List*
 scrbook.cls    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
scrlfile.sty    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)
scrlfile-hook.sty    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)
 scrlogo.sty    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (logo)
  keyval.sty    2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
tocbasic.sty    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize12pt.clo    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt)
typearea.sty    2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (type area)
geometry.sty    2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
geometry.cfg
   babel.sty    2024/08/29 v24.9 The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of b
abel
   czech.ldf    2008/07/06 v3.1a Czech support from the babel system
babel-czech.tex
babel-sanskrit-devanagari.tex
fontspec.sty    2024/05/11 v2.9e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
  xparse.sty    2024-08-16 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2024-08-16 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-luatex.def    2024-05-08 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
fontspec-luatex.sty    2024/05/11 v2.9e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

 fontenc.sty    2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
fontspec.cfg
  ts1cmr.fd    2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
 ***********

)


I can't reproduce the problem. Unrelated, but I recommend \babelhyphenation[czech]{Ma-há-bhá-ra-ta}, because bh should not be split.

show the full  log-file of the failing example.

@Ulrike Fischer: Log was added. Thanks a lot for your time.

Works for me, too, and the log file seems ok. But I’m on TeXLive. I'm trying to guess what’s happening.
